# How to get content type from blobstore by blobkey?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I get blobkey from datastore.
Now I want to use this blobkey to get content type of blob in blobstore.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

```
BlobInfoFactory bif = new BlobInfoFactory();
BlobKey bk = new BlobKey("<your blobkey>");
BlobInfo blobInfo = bif.loadBlobInfo(bk);

if(blobInfo == null)
    // The blob with the provided blobkey does not exists
else
    String contentType = blobInfo.getContentType();
```